# How to draw a sample of size n from a standard normal distribution?

Tags: random, stata

I know how to generate a sample of size *n* but am not sure how to get, say, 500 samples of 10 numbers in each sample (a 10 x 500 matrix).

In R I'd use `replicate`. What would be the equivalent of it in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
clear

set obs 500

forvalues i = 1/10 {
    gen sample`i' = rnormal()
}
```

Comment: Note that -- although this is what the OP asks for -- it might be as or more practical to `generate` a single sample of size 5000 and subdivide by `gen subsample = ceil(_n/500)` or `gen subsample = ceil(_n/10)`.  Much depends on what is going to come next!

Comment: Yes this is what I need. Thank you both!

Comment: @TZ Accepting the answer would give yourself and also Cybernike a reputation boost.